# I can't adjust screen brightness of my laptop anymore

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, laptop

My laptop has keyboard buttons for adjusting screen brightness. After a Debian Squeeze re-installation, they don't work no more.

[**laptop**] Acer TravelMate 6592; I use <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd><</kbd> to decrease the brightness and <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to increase it.

Comment: These things can sometimes be brand/model specific so a bit of information about the laptop in question might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the case that it got removed in the latest Debian Squeeze kernel (which is where the problem was), and it's now put back in 2.6.38. I say that because it was working way before Squeeze was released (and I only use pristine Debian kernel packages).

Answer (score 2):

Is it a problem of key mapping or a problem of acpi support ?

Check in `/proc/acpi/` if you have some entries like this one : `/proc/acpi/video/GFX0/LCDD/brightness`

If you find it, try to set a value maybe like this :

```
echo "4" > /proc/acpi/video/GFX0/LCDD/brightness
```

Comment: I don't have the "**/prc/acpi/video**" directory. My kernel is **2.6.32** on Debian.

Comment: What distro do you use?

Comment: I use Ubuntu, but with a kernel on my own (2.6.37).

Answer (score 1):

Add "acpi_osi=Linux" to loader

---

Example:

```
title Arch Linux
root (hd0,1)
kernel /vmlinuz26 root=/dev/sda5 ro acpi_osi=Linux
initrd /kernel26.img
```

Comment: What is `loader`?

Comment: I've tried this, and I'm, still sitting with the problem.

Comment: It's a /boot/grub/menu.lst

Comment: In my situation it helped me.

Comment: SO you can now adjust brightness using special laptop shortcuts, as in my case?

Comment: Yes. I use "Fn"+ "key arrows"

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your brightness with root user by typing:

```
echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/<xxx>/brightnes
```

Then, you can follow this link:
https://askubuntu.com/a/82320/301773

Comment: For example  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness  for thinkpads